# Python Pandas Create Multiple dataframes by slicing data at certain locations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I am new to Python and data analysis using programming. I have a long csv and I would like to create DataFrame dynamically and plot them later on. Here is an example of the DataFrame similar to the data exist in my csv file

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{"a" : [4 ,5, 6, 'a', 1, 2, 'a', 4, 5, 'a'],
"b" : [7, 8, 9, 'b', 0.1, 0.2, 'b', 0.3, 0.4, 'b'],
"c" : [10, 11, 12, 'c', 10, 20, 'c', 30, 40, 'c']})
```

As seen, there are elements which repeated in each column. So I would first need to find the index of the repetition and following that use this for making subsets. Here is the way I did this.

```
find_Repeat = df.groupby(['a'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df if
df.shape[0] > 1 else None)

repeat_idxs = find_Repeat.index[find_Repeat['a'] == 'a'].tolist()
```

If I print repeat_idxs, I would get

```
[3, 6, 9]
```

And this is the example of what I want to achieve in the end

```
dfa_1 = df['a'][Index_Identifier[0], Index_Identifier[1])
dfa_2 = df['a'][Index_Identifier[1], Index_Identifier[2])
dfb_1 = df['b'][Index_Identifier[0], Index_Identifier[1])
dfb_2 = df['b'][Index_Identifier[1], Index_Identifier[2])
```

But this is not efficient and convenient as I need to create many DataFrame like these for plotting later on. So I tried the following method

```
dfNames = ['dfa_' + str(i) for i in range(len(repeat_idxs))] 

dfs = dict()
for i, row in enumerate(repeat_idxs):
    dfName = dfNames[i]
    slices = df['a'].loc[row:row+1]
    dfs[dfName] = slices
```

If I print dfs, this is exactly what I want.

```
{'df_0': 3    a
4    1
Name: a, dtype: object, 'df_1': 6    a
7    4
Name: a, dtype: object, 'df_2': 9    a
Name: a, dtype: object}
```

However, if I want to read my csv and apply the above, I am not getting what's desired. I can find the repeated indices from csv file but I am not able to slice the data properly. I am presuming that I am not reading csv file correctly. I attached the csv file for further clarification [csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1qewogk4mgve9b5/result.csv?dl=0)

Comment: We need to know a little more about the repetition in order to help you detect it efficiently. Do you know that the repeated characters will always be the column names? Or are you looking for any repetition at all (including repeated numbers)? Or just repetition of strings?

Comment: Thanks sundace for your help. Yes these repeated strings are always in the columns which actually are helping me to slice the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

## Loop over and slice

Detect the repeat row indices and then loop over to slice contiguous chunks of the dataframe, ignoring the repeat rows:

```
# detect rows for which all values are equal to the column names
repeat_idxs = df.index[(df == df.columns.values).all(axis=1)]
slices = []
start = 0
for i in repeat_idxs:
    slices.append(df.loc[start:i - 1])
    start = i + 1
```

The result is a list of dataframes `slices`, which are the slices of your data in order.

## Use pandas groupby

You could also do this in one line using pandas groupby if you prefer:

```
grouped = df[~(df == df.columns.values).all(axis=1)].groupby((df == df.columns.values).all(axis=1).cumsum())
```

And you can now iterate over the groups like so:

```
for i, group_df in grouped:
    # do something with group_df
```

Comment: Works well! Thanks sundance